# Get products in WooCommerce by multiple taxonomy criterias

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I'm currently creating a new shop for a friend. It contains a couple artists selling their merchandise in different forms e.g. shirts, hoodies, prints, etc.

I used CPT UI and ACF to create a new "Artist" post type, so I have one template and the functions inside the "functions.php".

I want to have different sections in the template. For example all the shirts by the artist, all the prints, all the hoodies each in an own section. So far so good.

But now I got myself the function to get those products:

```
function getProductByTags($type, $artist) {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'tax_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
          'terms'    => $type,
          'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
          'terms'    => $artist,
          'operator' => 'IN',
        )
      ),
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    foreach( $loop as $product ) {
        print_pre($product); //developer function with "<pre>".print_r($val)."</pre>";
    }
}
```

But I get all the products, because somehow the filter of "type" AND "artist" don't work somehow. Also the result is some kind of weird array including empty fields instead of only the product and it's information.

Is there a way to get only "Shirts" by "Artist", so I can go on in the template?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind – found out, that I forgot:

```
"field" => "name"
```